# Call a Kotlin suspend function from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a Kotlin library that I'm attempting to call from Java. I haven't worked with Kotlin before.

The Kotlin library function is as follows:

```kotlin
suspend fun decode(jwt: String): UsefulThing {
    // does a bunch of stuff, removed for brevity.
    return otherthing.getUsefulThing(jwt)
}
```

How can I call this from Java? So far I've tried:

```java
Continuation<UsefulThing> continuation = new Continuation<>() {

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
        return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void resumeWith(@NotNull Object o) {
        System.out.println("Result of decode is " + o);
    }

};

// Call decode with the parameter and continuation.
Object result = UsefulThingKt.decode(JWT, continuation);

// result is COROUTINE_SUSPENDED
```

I never see any console output. Looks like the continuation is never called, or it's run in another context. I've pored over other answers and coroutines seem to have gone through a number of iterations - I can't find an explanation that really makes sense to me.

I should note that I'm running on Java 11.

How can I simply call the kotlin function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggest to not even try. Suspend functions were never meant for Java interop.

Instead, convert it on the Kotlin side to something that Java understands - to `CompletableFuture`:

```kotlin
fun decodeAsync(jwt: String): CompletableFuture<UsefulThing> = GlobalScope.future { decode(jwt) }
```

We can freely mix Java and Kotlin code in a single module, so you can create such wrapper inside your project.

Depending on your case you could use `GlobalScope` (in Java we don't have structured concurrency) or you could create a custom `CoroutineScope` and handle its lifecycle manually.

Comment: You need to add `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` dependency.